# When an element goes through nuclear decay, and the daughter product is reactive with the parent product, is there an immediate chemical reaction?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

When fission occurs, there is a new daughter element.  This can react with the parent material. 
1. Does it, and if so, how quickly?
2. If not, why not?

Comment: Fission releases large amounts of energy, pushing the products apart the products: Taken from Wikipedia: "When a uranium nucleus fissions into two daughter nuclei fragments, about 0.1 percent of the mass of the uranium nucleus[7] appears as the fission energy of ~200 MeV. For uranium-235 (total mean fission energy 202.5 MeV), typically ~169 MeV appears as the kinetic energy of the daughter nuclei, which fly apart at about 3% of the speed of light, due to Coulomb repulsion."

Comment: one should add to Jim's comment that in order for chemical bonds to appear the relative energies should be in the region of the bonding energies. Chemical binding will happen after the daughter slows down due to scatters and meets an appropriate nucleus.

Comment: the product might be ionized, changing its chemical properties

Comment: @DOS4004 The chunk of nucleus ejected at 0.03c is very unlikely to take its electrons with it on the way out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could happen. Uranium is naturally existing and there is the possibility of very asymmetric fragmentation into Oxygen or Fluor, although such event is much less common than fragmenting into 3/5 and 2/5 of the total mass. Also there can occur ternary fission, where such elements are more commonly emitted, but is also a less probable event. Such elements we know can react chemically with Uranium and form chemical compounds.

How quickly? Is kind of hard to calculate, but can be estimated. The Oxygen emitted would have an energy ranging from 10-100 MeV. It could be stopped in some centimeters of the material in about $\mu s$ after which it would gain electrons in nanoseconds. And the reaction time could maybe be nanoseconds too. So in this estimation, the addition of such different times would yield in the $\mu s$ range.